# jQuery Mobile $.mobile.changePage post to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to create a mobile *(obviously)* website. I have a list of items which are created dynamically based off an AJAX request. This works well!

The next thing is that these list items need to link to another "page" which would require a parameter being sent to it.

The code I'm using is:

```
$("#cwCountries [data-role='listview'] a").live("click", function() {
    var dataurl = $(this).data("url");
    if(dataurl != null) {
        $.mobile.changePage($("#cwCountrySpec"), {
            type: "post",
            data: dataurl
        });
    }
});
```

Which does change to the `cwCountrySpec` page as you'd expect. As you can see I'm using the second parameter in `$.mobile.changePage` to pass the data through that I want my already-existent page to be able to receive and make use of.

I can intercept the change to `cwCountrySpec` with this code:

```
$("#cwCountrySpec").live('pagebeforecreate', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

But when I check the console, the `data` value is returned as `undefined`.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

**Edit**
Well that's a shame...

I've just check the jQuery Mobile Methods docs, and it states,

> Used only when the 'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.

That sucks. So how else can I send data between a page change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's a shame...

I've just check the jQuery Mobile Methods docs, and it states,

> Used only when the 'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.

That sucks. So how else can I send data between a page change?

**Edit:** Also seems that the developers don't want to include `routes` as part of the framework, unlike Sencha.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the 'dataurl' value to a global variable, and then picking-up the value of that global variable when the '#cwCountrySpec' page loads.

```
var tmp_data;
$("#cwCountries [data-role='listview'] a").live("click", function() {
    var dataurl = $(this).data("url");
    if(dataurl != null) {
        tmp_data = dataurl;
        $.mobile.changePage($("#cwCountrySpec"));
    }
});
```

```
$("#cwCountrySpec").live('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    console.log(tmp_data);
});
```

---- EDIT ----

When you load the information into the new page, you can check to see if that page is empty or not so the page is only loaded once.

```
$("#cwCountrySpec").live('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    if ($("#cwCountrySpec div[data-role='content']").is(':empty')) {
        $("#cwCountrySpec div[data-role='content']").load(tmp_data);
    }
    console.log(tmp_data);
});
```

Comment: This is how I was doing it before (I'm on about my third revision) but I want to be able to store state between pages, and link back to them. I should have said this before, but I'd quite like to be able to link pages similar to `/#cwCountry/code` :)

Comment: When you load the data into the page container you can check to see if it is empty and only load the data if it is empty... See edit above.

Comment: I hate global variables, but this does the job.